# Data are not shown in BroadcastReceiver using Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to use **Firebase** in my application and show the **token** when calling the service and `Broadcast`! I write the below codes, but it didn't show any more in the `textview`!

**MyFCMInstance :**

```
public class MyFCMInstance extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public static final String TOKEN_BROADCAST = "fcmtokenbroadcast";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String CurrentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (CurrentToken != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("Token");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.d("token", "Refreshed token: " + CurrentToken);
            storeToken(CurrentToken);
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(TOKEN_BROADCAST));

        } else {
            onTokenRefresh();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e("FCM Instance", "Token : " + refreshedToken);

        // store token
        storeToken(refreshedToken);

        // send broadcast
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(TOKEN_BROADCAST));
    }

    private void storeToken(String token) {
        SharedPrefsManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).storeToken(token);
    }
}
```

**SharedPrefsManager codes:**

```
public class SharedPrefsManager {

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "FCMPrefs";
    private static final String KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "Token";
    private static Context mContext;
    private static SharedPrefsManager mInstance;

    public SharedPrefsManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefsManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefsManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public boolean storeToken(String token) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
        editor.apply();

        return true;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = preferences.getString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);

        return token;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tokenTV;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tokenTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tokenText);
        context = MainActivity.this;
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                tokenTV.setText(SharedPrefsManager.getInstance(context).getToken());
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyFCMInstance.TOKEN_BROADCAST));
    }
}
```

How can I fix it and show the **token** in `TextView` ?

Comment: storeToken(refreshedToken); function call should be before sendBroadcast()

Comment: @Aravindraj, Thanks my friend, but not work me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTokenRefresh()` method is only called once after you install your application. SO in your code it will only show token once and that too only first time.
Override onCreate() method in your fcm service class and do something like this

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String CurrentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (CurrentToken!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent("device_id");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.d("token", "Refreshed token: " + CurrentToken);
            appSharedPreferences.putString("device_id",CurrentToken);
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(TOKEN_BROADCAST));

        }
        else {
          onTokenRefresh();


                   }
}
```

Comment: also keep your send broacast code in token refresh method too as for the first time your broadcast will be sent from token refresh method

Comment: Thanks my friend for your helps, can you change this code `appSharedPreferences.putString("device_id",CurrentToken);` with my above codes? please

Comment: I'm amateur and I really need this help

Comment: Thanks man, I update my post and I added your codes into my codes! but just show once install and when run again application not show again token! I should uninstall and re-install app ta show me again Token. please see my update post and help me.

Comment: I tried with your code and it is working properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set broadcast call after save shared pref call.

```
public class MyFCMInstance extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public static final String TOKEN_BROADCAST = "fcmtokenbroadcast";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.e("FCM Instance", "Token : " + refreshedToken);

        // store token
        storeToken(refreshedToken);

        // send broadcast
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(TOKEN_BROADCAST));
    }

    private void storeToken(String token){
        SharedPrefsManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).storeToken(token);
    }
}


public boolean storeToken(String token) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
        editor.commit();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: check my update answer and try this one, also add login in your broadcast...and confirm the call is working or not